# Варежки и рукавицы

Tags: значение-слов

У нас на Украине слова "варежки" нет вообще. Есть рукавицы (рукавички) и перчатки. В России на то, которое не перчатки, говорят "варежки". Но как быть с рабочими рукавицами, с рукавичкой-прихваткой? Они тоже называются варежки? В чем разница?

Answer (score 4):

В России есть и варежки, и рукавицы. Рукавицы — более общее название. И варежки назвать рукавицами можно всегда, а вот рукавицы называют варежками, только если они предназначены для того, чтобы руки не мёрзли, и желательно, чтоб ещё и вязанными были. Так что, если имеете в виду холщовые рабочие рукавицы, то варежками их не называют.

Answer (score 3):

[21 октября 2006 года. 08:00](http://wobla.ru/news/1050997.aspx)

> Если обратиться к истории, то оказывается, что рукавицы шьют, варежки — вяжут. В Череповце еще до середины прошлого века были только рукавицы. Слово варежки привезли в наш город жители южных областей, приехавшие на строительство завода. На Руси рукавица являлась не только одеждой, но и доспехам, зимой под кожаную рукавицу поддевали вязаную, которая называлась варьга. Наши предки очень четко различали рукавицы и варежки, была даже пословица «Нужда рукавицу с варьгой сроднила», настолько беден, что не может иметь обе вещи.

Comment: Ну это уже диалектные особенности. В Череповце вообще цакали, насколько помню. *Шла овцА из под ЧереповцА, да как стукнецА, перевернецА*.

 А если обратится к истории, то сперва варежки и рукавицы спокойно друг друга заменяли в зависимости от местности, а смысловое разделение произшло уже позднее.

Answer (score 2):

> У нас на Украине слова "варежки" нет вообще.

Угу, как же. Слова нет, а варежки есть. :-)

Много раз слышал на Украине слово *"варежки"*. Оно и употребляется в разговоре, и всем понятно. Не является странным и необычным словом.

Другое дело, что в *литературном* украинском языке я этого слова что-то не припоминаю. Но тут такое дело... как бы это политически нейтрально написать... в современном украинском бывают некоторые надуманные условности и странности, которые в разговорной речи не очень-то встречаются или соблюдаются.

> Есть рукавицы (рукавички) и перчатки. В России на то, которое не перчатки, говорят "варежки". Но как быть с рабочими рукавицами, с рукавичкой-прихваткой?

**Собственно ответ.** *Рабочие рукавицы* и *рукавичка-прихватка*, я думаю, это вполне правильные названия для употребления как в России, так и на Украине.

(Ещё добавлю в скобках. А вот как раз слово *"перчатки"* в литературном варианте на Украине -- это *"рукавички"*. Хотя в разговоре обычно всё-таки разделяют по смыслу приблизительно так:
перчатки -- кожаные (ну или резиновые);
варежки -- вязаные;
рукавицы -- более широкое значение, но обычно матерчатые или меховые, где нет разделения на пальцы, кроме большого.

Можно дополнять и уточнять, то что я написал в скобках.)

С уважением к [[@Amano](/users/11/amano)](/users/11/amano) и его вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Чего-то я не понял вопроса.
Как с ними быть? Надевать на руки, вестимо.

Рукавицы и варежки - в общем-то синонимы. Правда частичные. 
Я так понимаю, что любая варежка - рукавица, но не любая рукавица варежка. Но смысл этого разделения несколько сменился со временем.

Исторически варежка это "вареная рукавица" - шерсть варили, технологию эту завезли варяги, из-за созвучия, кстати, самих варягов тоже стали считать этимологическими предками варежки. 
Но с тех пор много воды утекло, варежки стали не только шерстяные, единственно это название не распространилось на рабочие рукавицы.

Что еще тут сказать - не знаю.

А валенки и сапоги Вас не смущают?

Answer (score 1):

> В чем разница?

За украинский говорить не буду, а в русском "варежка" - теплая рукавица. Обычно - шерстяная, но не обязательно. [[@Яzz](/users/1864/%D1%8Fzz)](/users/1864/%D1%8Fzz) и [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus) правы.